# Get domains name from full URL

Tags: php, hyperlink, parse-url

I have a txt file (links.txt) There are thousands of links in it

I want to sort all the links using the following code

```
<?php
    function get_domain($url)
    {
        $pieces = parse_url($url);
        $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : $pieces['path'];
        if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
            return $regs['domain'];
        }
            return false;
        }
        print get_domain("http://mail.somedomain.co.uk"); // outputs 'somedomain.co.uk'
?>
```

How to call file 1 and arrange them and save them again?

## Update

In my file (domains.txt) there are about 10,000 domains
I want to filter domains with the above code

**for example:**

Before:

```
http://www.example.com/about
www.example.net/index.php
http://subdomain.example.org/
http://www.example.co/page-1
http://www.example.co.uk
```

After:

```
example.com
example.net
example.org
example.co
example.co.uk
```

Comment: You can save the each link to database, then create a script that will retrieve all of them sorted.

Comment: `file`, loop over the resulting array, do the manipulation required on each array element, write the whole thing back using `file_put_contents`.

Comment: @CBroe Can you show me a code sample?

Comment: @CBroe just seen my answer essentially does exactly what you suggest. Not sure on the etiquette/standard here but if you add as an answer I'm happy to delete my own!

Comment: @LeonardChallis no worries, all good. (Mine was a comment only after all.)

Answer (score 1):

In theory it's as simple as:

```
$file = file('domains.txt');
for ($x=0;$x<count($file);$x++) {
    $file[$x] = get_domain($file[$x]);
}
sort($file);
file_put_contents('domains.txt', $file);
```

But, depending on the size of your domains file this may be slow and/or take up a lot of resources, possibly even crash. You don't mention whether this is a one-off or something that would happen often, but if this is an issue then other solutions would include:

- Saving into a database, as suggested by @Karlo Kokkak (one example on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515439/handle-large-file-with-php))
- Use the command line, if you have access. If this were the case you'd probably be better skipping PHP altogether and using command line functions

Note: if you do go for the PHP above, you may need to look into increasing [PHP's time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in that script.